# Dump output from REPL

Tags: bash, dump

I'm writing SML programs, and I'd like a way to quickly see the output from running a program in the REPL without actually running the REPL (to quickly see if a program has syntax errors - I plan to use this as a make program for .sml files in vim to view the output inside vim).. Currently, I have this:

`sml file.sml | echo -e "\004"`

So it runs the program, and then echoes Ctrl-D to exit the REPL. The problem is that its too quick to send the Ctrl-D key, so there is no output. I tried this too:

`sml file.sml | sleep 2 ; echo -e "\004"`

But that isn't doing it either. Any ideas on how I can get a dump of the output from the REPL?

Comment: You might wand to look at [Expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)

Answer (score 3):

No, the problem is that you are misunderstanding how pipes work.

In Unix pipelines, data flows **from left to right** (the same direction as written text in English) – the first program's output becomes the second program's input. But the pipes are unidirectional; the second program's output is not sent to the first program.

When you run `sml file.sml | echo -e "\004"`, you **aren't** echoing Ctrl+D to `sml`. Instead, you are **piping `sml`'s output to the `echo` command** – where it gets discarded, since `echo` does not use stdin.

1. keyboard → `sml file.sml` → `echo -e "\004"` → screen

Your second attempt, `sml file.sml | sleep 2 ; echo -e "\004"`, has a similar problem – the output of `sml` is sent to `sleep` (which also discards the input it receives). However, there is another problem: the `echo` command now isn't part of the pipeline at all; you could say that `|` has a higher precedence than `;`. (You can **group commands using parentheses**; e.g. `a | (b; c; d)`.)

1. keyboard → `sml file.sml` → `sleep 2` → screen
2. keyboard → `echo -e "\004"` → screen

As already said above, both attempts are written in the **wrong direction**. If you wanted to send the `\004` character to `sml`, the pipeline should have been written like this:

```
echo -e "\004" | sml file.sml
```

in which, `sml`'s output goes to the screen, where it should.

There is **another problem**, however. You are also **confusing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keypress with the "end of input"** event.

The translation of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> into "end of input" only happens at terminal device layer – in other words, only when you enter the Ctrl+D character into your terminal window. However, when you use `echo -e "\004"` in a pipe, it is *not* automagically translated to "end of input"; instead, the actual byte 004 [octal] is written.

If you want to actually tell the program that there is no more input, then *do not write anything*. Use a command that outputs nothing – for example, `echo -n` or `true`, or just redirect input from the `/dev/null` file.

```
echo -n | sml file.sml

sml file.sml < /dev/null
```